# Default value pattern for Golang

Tags: go

I have this:

```
port := os.Getenv("huru_api_port") ||  ":8000"
```

that doesn't compile, Golang doesn't recognize that as syntax for defaulting to ":8000" if huru_api_port is empty/undefined.

Is there a good way to do this? On a side note, why is it ":8000" instead of "8000", for example:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
```

Comment: To your second question: `http.ListenAndServe` doesn't take a port number as string for its first argument, it takes the address of a network interface to bind to. `":8000"` is the address of the network interface that accepts connections from all remote hosts connecting from port `8000`. Contrast `"127.0.0.1:8000"` which is the address of the network interface that accepts connections only from local loopback (`127.0.0.1`) on port `8000`.

Answer (score 3):

[`os.LookupEnv`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv) will return the environment variable as a string and a boolean indicating whether or not the variable was set, so you'll either get

```
v, ok = "something", true
// or, if the env var isn't set
v, ok = "", false
// or, if the env var is set but empty:
v, ok = "", true
```

Use it like:

```
var port string
var ok bool
if port, ok = os.LookupEnv("huru_api_port"); !ok {
    port = ":8000"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy shorthand way to do that in Go, but for your case, you can use `LookupEnv` instead, which returns the value (if set) and a boolean indicating whether the key was found in the environment:

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv

Answer (score 1):

I would use [LookupEnv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv). It offers a `boolean` that will be false if the variable is not set.

The `:8000` means the listener will bind to all the network interfaces. You can think of it differing from `127.0.0.1:8000` which would only bind to the loopback interface.

Comment: do they tho - idk